# Azure - call Storage rest api for list blobs

Tags: c#, rest, azure

What I am trying to do is connect to the Azure Storage Rest API List Blobs. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx

I have tried to follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx in order to specify the authorization header however I get a 403 error - forbidden.

Code:

```
Uri address = new Uri("https://account.blob.core.windows.net/$logs?restype=container&comp=list");
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(address);
req.Headers["x-ms-date"] = "2013-09-04";
req.Headers["x-ms-version"] = "2012-02-12";
req.Method = "GET";

string StringToSign =  "GET\n"
    + "\n" // content encoding
    + "\n" // content language
    + "\n" // content length
    + "\n" // content md5
    + "\n" // content type
    + "\n" // date
    + "\n" // if modified since
    + "\n" // if match
    + "\n" // if none match
    + "\n" // if unmodified since
    + "\n" // range
    + "x-ms-date: 2013-09-04\nx-ms-version:2012-02-12\n" // headers
    + "/account/blob\ncomp:list\nrestype:container"; // resources

string accountName = "account";
string key = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(StringToSign));
req.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("SharedKey {0}:{1}", accountName, key);

HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Can anyone see any mistakes? Is there a tool which can generate the key? One thing I am not sure of is I am encoding/hashing the string correctly.

Thanks,
Andrew

Update with latest code. This code gives me a Forbidden error.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
string StringToSign = "GET\n"
    + "\n" // content encoding
    + "\n" // content language
    + "\n" // content length
    + "\n" // content md5
    + "\n" // content type
    + "\n" // date
    + "\n" // if modified since
    + "\n" // if match
    + "\n" // if none match
    + "\n" // if unmodified since
    + "\n" // range
    + "x-ms-date: " + dt.ToString("R") + "\nx-ms-version:2012-02-12\n" // headers
    + "/account/$logs\ncomp:list\nrestype:container";

string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, "accountkey", "account");
string method = "GET";
string urlPath = "https://account.blob.core.windows.net/$logs?restype=container&comp=list";
Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = method;
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dt.ToString("R"));
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-02-12");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Comment: When you say "is there a tool that can generate the key" it makes me suspicious.  You are getting the key from the azure storage page in the azure management portal right?

Comment: Yes. I am new to Azure - I have access to the portal, am I meant to use a key that is listed in the portal? Or construct the key via the code above?

Comment: I see now what you are doing with the "StringToSign".  That is not what the example is trying to tell you.  you are giving the result, not the value to to send.  Let me try to work something up.  The drag is that I have all this code at work.

Comment: You are meant to be using the key in the portal.  The key along with your account name are your authentication.  This is why you cant share those keys out to everyone.

Comment: Which key? The subscription ID? If that is the case, why does the MSDN have the above pages telling to go through all of these steps? Not trolling, just wondering. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues with the code above. But before that, first thing you would need is the key for your storage account. You can get it from Windows Azure Portal. Click on the storage account name in the portal and then click on "MANAGE ACCESS KEYS" as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Now for the issues:

The way you're creating the authorization header is incorrect. For creating the authorization header, you would need account name, account key and `StringToSign` from your code above. Try this code:

```
private static String SignThis(String StringToSign, string Key, string Account)
        {
            String signature = string.Empty;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedString);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            String authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                  "{0} {1}:{2}",
                  "SharedKey",
                  Account,
                  signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
        }
```

The function above will provide authorization header which you would need to pass as authorization.

2nd thing I noticed was that in the code for `StringToSign`, you're not passing the container name. So your `StringToSign` should be:

```
string StringToSign =  "GET\n"
    + "\n" // content encoding
    + "\n" // content language
    + "\n" // content length
    + "\n" // content md5
    + "\n" // content type
    + "\n" // date
    + "\n" // if modified since
    + "\n" // if match
    + "\n" // if none match
    + "\n" // if unmodified since
    + "\n" // range
    + "x-ms-date: 2013-09-04\nx-ms-version:2012-02-12\n" // headers
    + "/account/$logs\ncomp:list\nrestype:container"; // resources
```

You mentioned that you're quite new to Windows Azure. If I may suggest - implementing REST API has been done by a number of folks earlier also. Please take a look at what they have done instead of trying to do the same thing again. You may find these links useful:

http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/examples-of-the-windows-azure-storage-services-rest-api/

http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/ - Look at the REST API implementation in this project.

**UPDATE**

Here's the working code (just change the account name, key and the container name)

```
static void ListContainers()
{
    string Account = "account";
    string Key = "key";
    string Container = "$logs";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    string StringToSign = String.Format("GET\n"
        + "\n" // content encoding
        + "\n" // content language
        + "\n" // content length
        + "\n" // content md5
        + "\n" // content type
        + "\n" // date
        + "\n" // if modified since
        + "\n" // if match
        + "\n" // if none match
        + "\n" // if unmodified since
        + "\n" // range
        + "x-ms-date:" + dt.ToString("R") + "\nx-ms-version:2012-02-12\n" // headers
        + "/{0}/{1}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container", Account, Container);

    string auth = SignThis(StringToSign, Key, Account);
    string method = "GET";
    string urlPath = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list", Account, Container);
    Uri uri = new Uri(urlPath);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = method;
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dt.ToString("R"));
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-02-12");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. A couple of things: In SignThis you reference a variable called canonicalizedString , I presume this should be StringToSign ? Secondly what is canonicalizedString? Thirdly when I run this code I still get forbidden, and the key that is generated is different on each execution, is that right?

Comment: Sorry ... my bad ... cut/paste error :P. Yes, this should be `StringToSign`. So basically `StringToSign` is the canonicalizedString which is used for creating authorization header. Will it be possible for you to update your original post with the updated code so that we know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Added code. In the StringToSign variable do I need to include all the fields even if I have no value for that field?

Comment: It was a tricky error to catch :). Basically there's a whitespace after `x-ms-date:` in the following code: `+ "x-ms-date: " + dt.ToString("R") + "\nx-ms-version:2012-02-12\n"`. Get rid of the whitespace and the code should work fine. I have also updated my answer with the code I wrote.

Comment: You are the Azure master. I have asked a few other Azure questions and you always solve my issues. Thanks so much.

Comment: One last question, if I add a get parameter such as include=snapshots so my url is: https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list&include=snapshots do I need to change the way the resources are set in the StringToSign such as "/{0}/{1}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container\ninclude=snapshots ? I tried exactly this and get Forbidden. It seems if I add anything to the URI I get Forbidden

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I was able to help you out. Yes, you are correct. You would need to add all querystring parameters. One important thing is that the **querystring parameters must be sorted alphabetically**. So your code would be: `"/{0}/{1}\ncomp:list\ninclude=snapshots\nrestype:container`. Give it a try. It should work. For more information, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx. Scroll down to the section titled - "Constructing the Canonicalized Resource String". HTH.

Comment: SharedKey we need to pass a key or the string "SharedKey" only ??

Comment: Thank you! Alphabetically was the key for me. I'm impressed by the unnecessary complexity of this REST API.